# Unwanted GORM table creation

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have two domain classes, Person and Workshop. A Workshop has an owner of type Person, and many participants of type Person. A Person can be the participant of many workshops. When enrolling people in workshops I want to do so from the Workshop side like workshop.AddToParticipants() so here is how I set up my domain classes.

```
class Person {
    String name

    static hasMany = [enrolledWorkshops: Workshop]
    static belongsTo = [Workshop]

}

class Workshop {
    Date startDate
    Date endDate
    String name

    Person owner
    static hasMany = [participants: Person]
}
```

GORM correctly creates a WORKSHOP_PARTICIPANTS table with WORKSHOP_ID and PERSON_ID columns, and adds an OWNER_ID column to the WORKSHOP table. This is all good.

However, it ALSO creates a WORKSHOP_OWNER table with PERSON_ID and OWNER_ID columns! This makes no sense to me, and no matter how I try changing the GORM relationships I just can't get it to work how I want without this annoying extra table being created. How can I prevent the WORKSHOP_OWNER table from being created? Any help is greatly appreciated! (if it is of any help, I am using Grails 2.3.7)

Comment: shouldn't your belongsTo be on Workshop: `static belongsTo = [owner: Person]` ?

Comment: @NathanHughes I would think not because then I would have to add the workshops like person.AddToEnrolledWorkshops(). I went ahead and set it up like that though and I actually receive the following error when running the application: Error loading plugin manager: No owner defined between domain classes [class app.Person] and [class app.Workshop] in a many-to-many relationship. Example: static belongsTo = app.Workshop

Comment: They both appear to have hasMany of each other and also a belongsTo with one side the Person being a no reference relationship. I think if you removed static hasMany = [enrolledWorkshops: Workshop] then you would get required behaviour. Since a no reference relationship i.e. static belongsTo = [Workshop] allows the required behaviour "A Person can be the participant of many workshops"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get rid of the WORKSHOP_OWNER table you'd have to replace `Person owner` with `static belongsTo = [owner: Person]` in the Workshop class. But that would conflict with `static belongsTo = [Workshop]` in the Person class. Both can't be owners.

Try this:

```
class Person {
    String name
}

class Workshop {
    Date startDate
    Date endDate
    String name

    static belongsTo = [owner: Person]
    static hasMany = [participants: Participant]
}

class Participant {
    person person

    static belongsTo = [workshop: Workshop]
}
```

In the above example, a `Person` owns a `Workshop`, and a `Participant` is owned by a `Workshop`. The workshop table will get a owner_id to refer to the person, which gets rid of the workshop_owner table.

To add a `Person` to a `Workshop` you simply wrap it in a `Participant`

```
workshop.addToParticipants(new Participant(person: somePerson))
```

You'd loose the enrolledWorkshops property in `Person`, but you can accomplish the same thing with a query.

```
def workshops = Workshop.withCriteria {
    participants {
        eq 'person', somePerson
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked great. As a side question, would you happen to know if there's a way to have both reference and non reference GORM relationships declared in a belongsTo property? Such as static belongsTo = [owner: Person, Domain1, Domain2]

Comment: Based on my understand of the source code that reads the belongsTo property from domain classes, no. However, since belongsTo seems to be inherited, something like this (squashed) code might work: `class WorkshopOwner { static belongsTo = [Domain1, Domain2] } class Workshop extends WorkshopOwner {...}` You'd also have to consider which inheritance strategy to use. By default, properties in subclasses must be nullable. https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/blob/master/grails-datastore-core/src/main/groovy/org/grails/datastore/mapping/model/config/GormMappingConfigurationStrategy.java